# How to show Kendo Grid's columnMenu using script

Tags: kendo-ui

The Kendo Grid has a really nice column context menu (aka: columnMenu) which you can access by right clicking on each column header.  The menu is enabled by setting the field in the Kendo Grid to:

columnMenu: true

When the columnMenu is enabled, it displays the columns in the grid and allows you to show/hide columns, sort, and filter on them.  However, we have a requirement to move this column menu outside of the grid and tie it to a button.  So when the user clicks on a button, the column menu will appear.  Is there a way to invoke this via javascript?

This request is similar to one made by Michiel (March 5, 2012).  However, in that particular case, it was a request for the contextMenu for a different product, the Telerik MVC Grid.  The URL for Michiel's question is below as a reference:  http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-mvc/grid/how-to-show-column-context-menu-using-script.aspx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is as simple as triggering the click event of the column:

```
$("#grid .k-header-column-menu:first").click();
```

Here is a working demo: http://jsbin.com/ihivif/2/edit

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Atanas.  Is it also possible to move the column context menu to an X,Y coordinate and then trigger it via javascript?  So the following is desired:
1) user clicks on the button
2) the column context menu appears right under the button
3) user selects which column(s) to show or to hide in Kendo Grid
The response for Michiel's question seems to provide a way to position the menu.  Can we also do this for Kendo Grid?

Comment: Yes. I modified my jsbin demo.

Comment: That worked, thanks so much Atanas - doing sample code in jsbin helped a lot!

Comment: What if you have `columnMenu: false` and you simply want to show the columns list with checkboxes on some button click. Is this possible?