# How to access Kendo Grid's column menu only from outside the grid and add the filter option for specific columns in the column header

Tags: javascript, filter, kendo-ui, show-hide, kendo-grid

I am new to Kendo Grid and trying to use the columnMenu option.  I need to access the column Menu function (only the ability to show/hide columns from a button outside the grid.  This link allows me to do that and it is working fine.
[How to show Kendo Grid's columnMenu using script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13637475/how-to-show-kendo-grids-columnmenu-using-script)

But this still retains the columnMenu option in the column headers which I do not need. So after looking into it further, I was able to remove the column headers on the load using
defaultGrid.thead.find("[data-field=Address]>.k-header-column-menu").remove();
where Address is one of the columns in the grid. I still do need to have atleast one column with the columnMenu option, or else the solution in the above url does not work.

Using the solution in the link above, it also removes the filter option on the columns.  What I need to achieve is remove the Column Menu from all the column headers (and access the show/hide column option from outside the grid) and also have the filter option available to specific columns of the grid

Is this possible and how do I go about doing it?  Please help

Comment: Anybody has a solution to this query?

Comment: I need the same solution

Answer (score 19):

Not sure I got all requirements right, but something like this should work:

JS:

```
var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: [{
        foo: "foo",
        bar: "bar"
    }],
    filterable: true,
    columnMenu: true
}).getKendoGrid();

function showMenu() {
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    var fieldName = $(this).data("field");
    var th = $(grid.thead).find("th[data-field='" + fieldName + "']");

    $(th).find(".k-header-column-menu:first").click();
    $(".k-column-menu").parent().css({
        top: offset.top + $(this).outerHeight(),
        left: offset.left
    });
}

$(document).on("click", ".grid-menu", showMenu);
```

CSS:

```
.k-header-column-menu {
    visibility: hidden
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id='grid'></div>
<div>
    <button class='grid-menu' data-field="foo">Show foo menu</button>
    <button class='grid-menu' data-field="bar">Show bar menu</button>
</div>
```

([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/lhoeppner/p74JA/))

Another approach for just showing a menu with checkboxes while keeping the filter menu in the grid header:

Grid:

```
var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: [{
        foo: "foo",
        bar: "bar"
    }],
    filterable: true,
    columnMenu: false
}).getKendoGrid();
```

Create menu entries from grid.columns:

```
var ds = [];
for (var i = 0, max = grid.columns.length; i < max; i++) {
    ds.push({
        encoded: false,
        text: "<label><input type='checkbox' checked='checked' " +
              " class='check' data-field='" + grid.columns[i].field + 
              "'/>" + grid.columns[i].field + "</label>"
    });
}
```

Menu:

```
$("#menu").kendoMenu({
    dataSource: [{
        text: "Menu",
        items: ds
    }],
    openOnClick: true,
    closeOnClick: false,
    open: function () {
        var selector;
        // deselect hidden columns
        $.each(grid.columns, function () {
            if (this.hidden) {
                selector = "input[data-field='" + this.field + "']";
                $(selector).prop("checked", false);
            }
        });
    },
    select: function (e) {
        // ignore click on top-level menu button
        if ($(e.item).parent().filter("div").length) return;

        var input = $(e.item).find("input.check");
        var field = $(input).data("field");
        if ($(input).is(":checked")) {
            grid.showColumn(field);
        } else {
            grid.hideColumn(field);
        }
    }
});
```

([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/lhoeppner/WpDtH/3/))

Comment: Hey thanks for the go. The main issue we are trying to solve is the fact that when I hit the button I have to navigate through an additional Columns button. We are moving to kendo grid from slickgrid and in slickgrid we had this menu: http://www.dumpt.com/img/viewer.php?file=wazzmomuyandkga0vzlf.png

Comment: This shows the desired result: http://www.dumpt.com/img/viewer.php?file=hwgwnponet56satkwgc7.png

Comment: Chances are this isn't easily possible. I'll give this another day but we will probably just have to roll our own using the API

Comment: yeah, for that, I'd probably simply use a Kendo Menu; see edit for an example (probably a few things that might need ironing out)

Comment: Thanks man, that's pretty derned good. Yes we can take it from here :D

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty old thread, but after searching for similar things I found a post in the Terlerik forum where a user makes reference to "kendoColumnMenu".  For as much as I can tell this is undocumented.

It also shows how to add additional options to the menu that is created for saving grid state or other configuration options of your choice.

Here is the link to the post which also contains a link to the DOJO with working code: [Click Here](http://www.telerik.com/forums/grid-column-menu-only-in-one-column#6d94PE5530C9OpC4n5JhXA)

Hopefully this will help someone else searching for this.

Comment: @The Dread Pirate Stephen Not sure how you found out about that method, I couldn't find it anywhere in the API docs.  But it worked well for me!  Another note is that it doesn't work for a button element in IE 11, had to use a DIV as in the example and style it as a button.  Cheers!

Comment: I found the kendoColumnMenu() by looking at the source code for the Grid widget to see how it created the menu and if I could "steal" the implementation for my own purposes. Grid constructor/init() => _thead() => _columnMenu() => kendoColumnMenu()

Answer (score 0):

I made the kendo column menu include filter settings and it is worked for me,

```js
// column settings dropdown maker
function GridGorunumAyarlaMenu(GridName) {
  var ColumnMenuListHTML = "";
  var CheckBoxType = "";
  var LockSignType = "";
  var Col_uid = "";

  var GridColumns = $("#" + GridName).data("kendoGrid").columns;

  // column setting area
  $("#" + GridName + " .k-header").each(function(i, item) {
    for (var i = 0; i < GridColumns.length; i++) {
      if (GridColumns[i].uid == $(item).attr("id") && GridColumns[i].title != undefined) {


        if (GridColumns[i].hidden == true) {
          CheckBoxType = '<div  onclick=' + "ShowHideColumnSet('" + GridColumns[i].uid + "','" + GridName + "')" + ' class="checkbox checkbox-success input-group"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="Ch' + GridColumns[i].uid + '">';
        } else {
          CheckBoxType = '<div  onclick=' + "ShowHideColumnSet('" + GridColumns[i].uid + "','" + GridName + "')" + ' class="checkbox checkbox-success input-group"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="Ch' + GridColumns[i].uid + '" checked>';
        }

        var ColumnDiv = $(item).parent().closest("div");
        if (ColumnDiv.hasClass("k-grid-header-locked")) {
          LockSignType = '<i onclick=' + "LockUnlockColumn('" + GridColumns[i].uid + "','" + GridName + "')" + ' class="cLocked fa fa-lock pull-right"></i>';
        } else {
          LockSignType = '<i onclick=' + "LockUnlockColumn('" + GridColumns[i].uid + "','" + GridName + "')" + ' class="cLocked fa fa-unlock pull-right"></i>';
        }

        Col_uid = GridColumns[i].uid;

        ColumnMenuListHTML += '<li id="li' + Col_uid + '" class="d-flex justify-content-between"><a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle">' + CheckBoxType + '<label>' + $(item).text() + '</label></div></a>' + LockSignType + '</li>';
      }
    }
  });

  // send html inside the ul element
  $("#ColumnSettingsList").html(ColumnMenuListHTML);


  // Grid filter areas
  var FilterColumnDropdown = "";
  $("." + PageName + " #" + GridName + " .k-header").each(function(i, item) {
    for (var i = 0; i < GridColumns.length; i++) {
      if (GridColumns[i].uid == $(item).attr("id") && GridColumns[i].title != undefined) {
        FilterColumnDropdown += '<option value="' + GridColumns[i].field + '">' + GridColumns[i].title + '</option>';
      }
    }
  });
  $("#SutunBilsisiList").html(FilterColumnDropdown);
}

// Open/close column settings
function ShowColumnSettingDropdown(id) {
  var ColumnSetFirsDD = $("#ColumSettingsFirsDD");
  if (ColumnSetFirsDD.hasClass("MenuShow")) {
    ColumnSetFirsDD.removeClass('MenuShow');
    $("#ColumnSettingsList").removeClass('MenuShow');
    $("#FiltreSettingsList").removeClass('MenuShow');
  } else {
    ColumnSetFirsDD.addClass('MenuShow');
  }
}

// Show/hide show/hide settings
function ShowColumShowSetting() {
  var ColumnShowSet = $("#ColumnSettingsList");

  if (ColumnShowSet.hasClass("MenuShow")) {
    ColumnShowSet.removeClass('MenuShow');
  } else {
    ColumnShowSet.addClass('MenuShow');
    $("#FiltreSettingsList").removeClass('MenuShow');
  }
}

// Show/hide filter settings
function ShowFilterSetting() {
  var Liste = $("#FiltreSettingsList");

  if (Liste.hasClass("MenuShow")) {
    Liste.removeClass('MenuShow');
  } else {
    Liste.addClass('MenuShow');
    $("#ColumnSettingsList").removeClass('MenuShow');
  }
}

// Clear filter areas
function ColumnMenuFiltreTemizle() {
  $("#FiltreBirinciAlan").val("");
  $("#FiltreIkinciAlan").val("");
}

// Column Menu grid filtering
function ColumnMenuFiltrele() {
  // Grid value
  var grid = $("#Grid_SipHareketleri_" + SiparisKaydet_SiparisUstIDOku()).data("kendoGrid");
  var gridDataSource = grid.dataSource;

  var SelectedRow = $("#SutunBilsisiList").val();
  var BirinciAlan = $("#FiltreBirinciAlan").val();
  var IkinciAlan = $("#FiltreIkinciAlan").val();

  var Con1 = $("#ColumnFiltreCond1").val();
  var Con2 = $("#ColumnFiltreCond2").val();

  var filter = {
    logic: Con1,
    filters: []
  };
  var FilterField = SelectedRow;
  var filterOperator = Con2;

  filter.filters.push({
    field: FilterField,
    operator: filterOperator,
    value: BirinciAlan,
  });

  filter.filters.push({
    field: FilterField,
    operator: filterOperator,
    value: IkinciAlan,
  });

  if (BirinciAlan == "" || IkinciAlan == "") {
    gridDataSource.filter([]);
  } else {
    gridDataSource.filter(filter);
  }
}

// Lock/unclock Column
function LockUnlockColumn(ColumnID, GridName) {
  // ID of Li element
  var Li_id = "#li" + ColumnID;

  // Grid value
  var grid = $("#" + GridName).data("kendoGrid");

  // i element that show lock/unlock 
  var i_el = $(Li_id).children().closest('i');

  // Lock or unlock 
  if (i_el.hasClass("fa-lock")) {
    grid.unlockColumn($("#" + ColumnID).data("field"));
    i_el.removeClass("fa-lock");
    i_el.addClass("fa-unlock");
  } else {
    grid.lockColumn($("#" + ColumnID).data("field"));
    i_el.removeClass("fa-unlock");
    i_el.addClass("fa-lock");
  }
}

// Show/Hide Column
function ShowHideColumnSet(ColumnID, GridName) {
  // Column th element
  var id = "#Ch" + ColumnID

  // Grid Value
  var grid = $("#" + GridName).data("kendoGrid");

  // CheckBox
  var CheckBoxVal = $(id);

  // CheckBox show/hide
  if (CheckBoxVal.is(':checked')) {
    CheckBoxVal.removeAttr("checked");
    // Seçilen satırı gizleme işlemi
    grid.hideColumn($("#" + ColumnID).data("field"));
  } else {
    CheckBoxVal.attr('checked', 'checked');
    grid.showColumn($("#" + ColumnID).data("field"));
  }
}
```

```css
.ColMenuDropDown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

#ColumSettingsFirsDD {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  min-width: 110px;
}

#ColumnSettingsList {
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 250px;
  height: 290px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  right: -253px;
  top: 6px;
}

.dropdown-toggle::after {
  display: none;
}

.ColumnMenuFiltre {
  width: 300px;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

.MenuShow {
  display: block !important;
}

.cLocked {
  font-size: 16pt;
  padding: 6px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2022.3.913/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2022.3.913/styles/kendo.default-v2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ColMenuDropDown">
  <button id="GorunumAyarlaBtn" type="button" title="Görünüm Ayarla" name="GorunumAyarla" class="btn-primary btn btn-xs btn-default" style="margin-left:2px;" onclick="ShowColumnSettingDropdown();">
                                            <i class="fa fa-clone"></i> Column Menu
                                        </button>
  <ul id="ColumSettingsFirsDD">

    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
      <a id="GorunumColumnMenuBtn" class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#" onclick="ShowColumShowSetting();">Columns</a>
      <ul id="ColumnSettingsList" class="dropdown-menu">
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
      <a id="GorunumFiltreMenuBtn" class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#" onclick="ShowFilterSetting();">Filter</a>
      <ul id="FiltreSettingsList" class="dropdown-menu">
        <li>
          <div class="ColumnMenuFiltre">
            <span class="text-center"><b>show variables between this and this</b></span>
            <div class="row mt-2">
              <div class="col-sm-12">
                <label>Filtered Column</label>
                <select id="SutunBilsisiList" class="form-select">
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row mt-2">
              <div class="col-sm-12">
                <label>1. Value</label>
                <input id="FiltreBirinciAlan" class="form-control form-group-sm" type="text" />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row mt-2">
              <div class="col-sm-4">
                <select id="ColumnFiltreCond1" class="form-select">
                  <option value="and">and</option>
                  <option value="or">or</option>
                </select>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-8">
                <select id="ColumnFiltreCond2" class="form-select">
                  <option value="eq">Equal</option>
                  <option value="neq">Not Equal</option>
                  <option value="startswith">Starts With</option>
                  <option value="endswith">Ends With</option>
                  <option value="contains">Contains</option>
                  <option value="doesnotcontain">Not Contains</option>
                  <option value="isnull">Is Null</option>
                  <option value="isnotnull">Is Not Null</option>
                  <option value="isempty">Is Empty</option>
                  <option value="isnotempty">Is Not Empty</option>
                  <option value="hasnovalue">Has No Value</option>
                  <option value="hasvalue">Has Value</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row mt-2">
              <div class="col-sm-12">
                <label>2. Value</label>
                <input id="FiltreIkinciAlan" class="form-control form-group-sm" type="text" />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row mt-2 d-flex justify-content-around">
              <div class="col-sm-4">
                <button type="button" onclick="ColumnMenuFiltrele();" class="btn btn-danger">Filter</button>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-4">
                <button type="button" onclick="ColumnMenuFiltreTemizle();" class="btn btn-secondary">Clear</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```