# Tool bar Column Menu in kendo grid using angular js

Tags: kendo-grid, uitoolbar, datagridviewcolumn, kendo-ui-grid, kendo-contextmenu

How to put a column menu in toolbar of a kendo grid to select the columns as per need?

```
dataSource: $scope.kDisplayReceivedOrders,
            toolbar: ["save", "cancel",
                {
                    template:
                        '<button class="k-button k-button-icontext " ng-click="confirmReceivedOrder()" >Confirm</button>' +
                        '<button class="k-button "  ng-click="printReceivedOrderDetails()">Print</button>'
                }
            ],
```

Comment: Check the thread here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17224476/how-to-access-kendo-grids-column-menu-only-from-outside-the-grid-and-add-the-fi/41491474#41491474)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot insert the columnMenu froma a Kendo grid inside a toolbar because Kendo add it to the current grid.

But what you could do is a self implementation of the behavior of this menu inside your own toolbar. I have done it recently for a project.

What I have done:

- An angular component.
- When clicking on the component I read what columns are visible.

  - I do that throgh the `.getOptions()` and then inspecting the `columns` property of the object returned. The invisible columns will have a `hidden=true`.
- Then in the template I show all the columns with a checkbox to switch the visibility.
- `hideColumn()` and `showColumn()` should be attached to the action of checking or unchecking a checkbox.

Angular component controller:

```
init() {
 if(this.grid)
  this.columns = getColumns(this.grid.getOptions().columns);
}

checkbox(column) {
  column.visible === true ? this._objectViewService.grid.showColumn(column.field) : this._objectViewService.grid.hideColumn(column.field);
}
```

A method to convert from kendo defaults to my visualization system:

```
function getColumns(columns) {
 let cols = [];
 columns.forEach(column => cols.push({title: column.title, field:   column.field, visible: column.hidden !== undefined ? !column.hidden : true}));
 return cols;
}
```

The template:

```
<div class="columnDropdownComponent">
 <p class="title" ng-mouseover="$ctrl.init()">
  <button>Columns<span class="icon-navigation-down"></span></button>
 </p>
 <div class="dropdown">
  <div class="group">
   <label ng-repeat="column in $ctrl.columns" ng-class="{'checked': column.visible}">
    {{column.title}}
   <input type="checkbox" ng-model="column.visible" ng-click="$ctrl.checkbox(column)">
  </label>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did my answer help you?